# dtd not found (using saxon9he and altova)

Tags: xslt, dtd, saxon

I'm trying to process several xml files but they have a dtd that cannot be found, because I dont have it, I only have the xml files. How do I deal with that? Is there a way to make saxon ignore the dtds?

Thanks for help!

Comment: It is the XML parser that does the XML parsing and DTD resolution. Which version of Saxon do you use, on which platform (Java or .NET)? On .NET supping an `XmlReader` with `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.dtdprocessing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx` set to `Ignore` might do but of course usually a DTD defines stuff like entities later referenced in the XML, in that case ignoring does not work.

Comment: I am using saxon9he.jar

Comment: `jar` suggests you are using Java. How do you use Saxon, from the command line or in a Java application? Have you considered to provide a dummy DTD using a catalog (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/xml-catalogs.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to tell Saxon to tell the XML parser to ignore the DTD. Even if you aren't validating, the DTD is still needed to resolve entity references.

However, you can redirect it to a dummy DTD by using catalogs.